# Is it possible to put static XAML elements into an array?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I have static XAML elements... let say:

```
x:Name="elem1"
x:Name="elem2"
```

Is there a way to put them into an array to use them dynamic with C#? Something like:

```
"var_type"[] elements = {elem1, elem2};
```

Or is there a way to use this static elements somehow by using a string? Somehow in this way:

```
Convert."ToXAML-Element"("elem1").Width = 200;
```

Thank you in advanced for any help!

EDIT:

This works for me now:

```
object wantedNode = Parentelement.FindName("string");
if (wantedNode is FrameworkElement)
{
    FrameworkElement wantedChild = wantedNode as FrameworkElement;
    wantedChild.DataContext = pathdata[a];
    wantedChild.Width = 200;
}
```

But it is a bit cumbersome...

Comment: Can you detail a bit what are you trying to achieve. What kind of static xaml elements you have ? How do you want to used them ? (do you want to define them in xaml and use in code behind...)

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly you want to create objects out of xaml code to use them dynamically? if that is the case take a look at the xamlreader: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx

Comment: nope ... the xaml elements are static - created by hand